# How can I remove the use of 'block' from my macro to make it more usable?

Tags: rust

I've written this macro to expand arbitrary terms into a token list for parsing, which allows me to do this:

```
let q = query!({T::U32_(&foo.x)} > {T::U32(0)});
// [U32_(100), Greater, U32(0)]

let q = query!({T::U32_(&foo.x)} != {T::U32_(&bar)});
// [U32_(100), NotEqual, U32_(10)]

let q = query!(
  ({T::U32_(&foo.x)} > {T::U32(0)}) || 
  (({T::U32_(&bar)} == {T::U32(1)}) && ({T::U32_(&bar)} <= {T::U32(10)}))
);
// [Left, U32_(100), Greater, U32(0), Right, Or, Left, Left, U32_(10), 
//  Equal, U32(1), Right, And, Left, U32_(10), LesserEquals, U32(10),
//  Right, Right]
```

However, I find the syntax annoying; notice how each enum has to sit in its own `{ ... }` block to correctly expand into the final vec. I would much prefer this:

```
let q = query!(T::U32_(&foo.x) > T::U32(0));

let q = query!(T::U32_(&foo.x) != T::U32_(&bar));

let q = query!(
   (T::U32_(&foo.x) > T::U32(0)) || 
  ((T::U32_(&bar) == T::U32(1)) && (T::U32_(&bar) <= T::U32(10)))
);
```

I've been reading macro examples all day trying to figure this one out, but I can't figure out if there's a valid combination of tokens that will let me do this.

Help! How can I do this?

Full macro code on playpen: http://is.gd/VM71VQ

```
#![feature(trace_macros)]
#![allow(dead_code)]

#[derive(Debug)]
enum T<'a> {
  Left,
  Right,
  Equal,
  NotEqual,
  And,
  Or,
  Greater,
  Lesser,
  GreaterEquals,
  LesserEquals,
  U32(u32),
  U32_(&'a u32),
}

macro_rules! query(

  // Expand an inner block into its tokens
  ( EXPAND_BLOCK $x:block ) => (vec!( $x ));

  // Expand (
  ( ( ) => (vec!(T::Left));

  // Expand )
  ( ) ) => (vec!( T::Right ));

  // Expand &&
  ( && ) => (vec!( T::And ));

  // Expand >
  ( > ) => (vec!( T::Greater ));

  // Expand <
  ( < ) => (vec!( T::Lesser ));

  // Expand >=
  ( >= ) => (vec!( T::GreaterEquals ));

  // Expand >
  ( <= ) => (vec!( T::LesserEquals ));

  // Expand ==
  ( == ) => (vec!( T::Equal ));

  // Expand !=
  ( != ) => (vec!( T::NotEqual ));

  // Expand ||
  ( || ) => (vec!( T::Or ));

  // Expand ( ... ) into Left, query!(...), Right
  (( $($ps:tt)* )) => {
    {
      let mut rtn:Vec<T> = Vec::new();
      rtn.push(T::Left);
      for item in query!($($ps)*).into_iter() {
        rtn.push(item);
      }
      rtn.push(T::Right);
      rtn
    }
  };

  // Expand a syntax tree parent into it's immediate child elements
  // ie. { ... } into query!(...)
  ({ $($ps:tt)* }) => {
    query!(EXPAND_BLOCK { $($ps)* })
  };

  // Top level expansion into a query using syntax tree rules
  ($($ps:tt)*) => {
    {
      let mut rtn:Vec<T> = Vec::new();
      $(
        for item in query!($ps).into_iter() {
          rtn.push(item);
        }
      )*
      rtn
    }
  };
);

struct Expr {
  x: u32
}

fn main() {
  let foo = Expr { x: 100u32 };
  let bar = 10;

  // trace_macros!(true);

  let q = query!({T::U32_(&foo.x)} > {T::U32(0)});
  println!("{:?}", q);

  let q = query!({T::U32_(&foo.x)} != {T::U32_(&bar)});
  println!("{:?}", q);

  let q = query!(
    ({T::U32_(&foo.x)} > {T::U32(0)}) || 
    (({T::U32_(&bar)} == {T::U32(1)}) && ({T::U32_(&bar)} <= {T::U32(10)}))
  );
  println!("{:?}", q);
}
```

Comment: You may wish to comment on current answers to explain why they don't have enough detail - then answerers have the possibility of building on them or revising them.

Comment: @Shepmaster What do you mean? The only current answer is 'I guess its not possible'. That's neither authoritative (why is it categorically impossible?) nor a solution to my problem.

Comment: Answering *why is it categorically impossible* sounds like an enhancement to the answer, if the author chooses to add it. If it truly is impossible to do via macros, but it *is* possible to do via a compiler plugin, then that is one way to solve your problem. Sometimes problems can't be solved within certain constraints. ^_^ I don't know if that's the case here, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
#![feature(trace_macros)]

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Item {
    Value(u8),
    LParen,
    RParen,
    And,
    Or,
    LessThan,
    GreaterThan,
    LessThanEqual,
    Equal,
}

macro_rules! query0(
    ( ( $( $v:tt )* ) ) => ({
        let mut result = vec![Item::LParen];
        $( result.extend(query0!($v)) );*;
        result.push(Item::RParen);
        result
    });
    ( || )      => ( vec![Item::Or] );
    ( && )      => ( vec![Item::And] );
    ( < )       => ( vec![Item::LessThan] );
    ( > )       => ( vec![Item::GreaterThan] );
    ( <= )      => ( vec![Item::LessThanEqual] );
    ( == )      => ( vec![Item::Equal] );
    ( $v:expr ) => ( vec![Item::Value($v)] );
);

macro_rules! query(
    ( $( $v:tt )* ) => ({
        let mut result = vec![];
        $( result.extend(query0!( $v )) );*;
        result
    });
);

fn main() {
    //trace_macros!(true);

    let a = query!(5);
    println!("{:?}", a);

    let b = query!((1 < 3) == 5);
    println!("{:?}", b);

    let c = query!((42 > 0) || 
                   ((13 == 13) && (12 <= 99)));
    println!("{:?}", c);
}
```

([playpen link](http://is.gd/8gXK2F))

Let me know what parts are most interesting and I can explain those (after I've had a bit of sleep... ^_^).

Comment: For anyone else who finds this, you can add support for references in the expression using traits, like this: http://is.gd/uhRN4S

Comment: Fwiw, it's still slightly problematic that :tt resolves &foo as two tokens, so it doesn't seem like it's possible to directly insert references (eg. (&a > 0)) but since it works with identifiers I'm happy enough with it as is~

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is impossible with `syntax_rules!`. You can't use simple `$($ps:tt)*` syntax, because constructions like `T::U32_(&foo.x)` will be parsed incorrectly. And you can't use patterns like `($x:item $($ps:tt)*)` with macro recursion on second part, because `syntax_rules!` parser requires unambiguity (as noted in [the book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/advanced-macros.html#syntactic-requirements)). It forces you to introduce some delimiter tokens in your DSL, for example, comma: `query!(T::U32_(&foo.x), >, T::U32(0))`, but it's obviously uglier than your block syntax.

Possibly there is an option to take advantage of a [compiler plugin](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/plugins.html), but I'd prefer to build that eDSL using algebraic data types (in any case you will interpret it in runtime).